# Query to get schema names in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a logical / cleaner query to get all the schema names that I have created

```
select schema_name  
from "information_schema"."schemata"
```

AND

```
SELECT nspname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace;
```

Returns a superset of schema names that have system created schema which I don't need.

I just want the schema names that I have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query solved my problem

```
SELECT distinct pg_namespace.nspname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_inherits INNER JOIN
pg_catalog.pg_class ON (pg_inherits.inhrelid = pg_class.oid) INNER JOIN
pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON (pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid)
WHERE pg_namespace.nspname <> 'public';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering from `information_schema.schemata` the `pg_*` schemas and the `information_schema` itself:

```
SELECT * from information_schema.schemata 
WHERE NOT schema_name LIKE 'pg_%' AND schema_name <> 'information_schema'
```

Excluding the schemas owned by `postgres`, as suggested by Gordon, works only with the condition that `postgres` isn't the owner of any other schema but the system schemas. In case you created a schema with the user `postgres`, it will be excluded from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the built-in schemas, then use:

```
select schema_name
from "information_schema"."schemata"
where schema_owner <> 'postgres';
```

If you want the ones that you specifically created, then check for the ones where you are the owner.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    *,
    nspowner::regrole as role_name
from pg_namespace
where nspowner = 'postgres'::regrole;
```

returns all schemes where owner is `postgres` user. Change it to your user name to get schemes owned by you.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html